# Crack The Code Puzzle

Tags: cipher

During a secret mission, an agent gave the following code to the higher authorities

> AIM DUE OAT TIE MOD

However the information is in one word only and the rest are fake. To assist the authorities in understanding better, he also sent them a clue – If I tell you any one character of the code, you can easily find out the number of vowels in the code word.

Can you find out the code word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> TIE

Because,

> The only word with 1 vowel is MOD, so we rule out the letters M O D as they also belong to words with 2 vowels.
>  That leaves us with letters A I T E U that are always part of 2-vowels words, and the only word that combines these is TIE